# Minimizing a function of two discrete variables

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, optimization

I have a question. Consider the function 
$$E(x,y,V,\mu)=\frac{1}{2}[x(x-1)+y(y-1)]+Vxy-\mu(x+y),$$
where $\mu$ and $V$ are continuous variables, and $x$ and $y$ are discrete variables. (This is energy of a physical system, known as the extended Hubbard model in strong coupling regime.) I'd like to minimize it analytically with respect to $x$ and $y$ for given $\mu$ and $V$.

It is easy to numerically check that $\{x,y\}=\{1,1\},\{2,2\},\{3,3\}$, etc. minimize $E$ if $V=0$ and $\mu$ is in the range $(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)$, etc., respectively. Similarly, $\{x,y\}=\{1,0\},\{1,1\},\{2,1\}$, etc. (note that for example $\{1,0\}$ and $\{0,1\}$ have same value) minimize $E$ if $V<1$ and $\mu$ is in the range $(0,V),(V,1+V),(1+V,1+2V)$, etc., respectively. And finally, $\{x,y\}=\{1,0\},\{2,0\},\{3,0\}$, etc. minimize $E$ if $V>1$ and $\mu$ is in the range $(0,1),(1,2),(2,3)$, etc., respectively.

If we skip over the fact that $x$ and $y$ are discrete and then minimize $E$ via $\partial E/\partial x=\partial E/\partial y=0$, this yields $x=y=(2\mu+1)/(2+2V)$. Now, I can impose the integer condition by defining $x=n_x+\alpha_x$ and $y=n_y+\alpha_y$, where $n_{x/y}$ are integer and $-1/2<\alpha_{x/y}=x/y-n_{x/y}<1/2$. Simple rearrangement gives the final results:
$$
n_{x/y}-1<\frac{2\mu-V}{2+2V}<n_{x/y},
$$
which is only correct when $V=0$. When $V=0$, one has $n_{x/y}-1<\mu<n_{x/y}$, implying that $x/y=n_{x/y}$ (cf. with the numerical results given above: for instance $0<\mu<1$ implies $x/y=n_{x/y}=1$). For non-zero $V$, the above condition gives obviously wrong answer, as can be checked with the numerical results. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Any idea or suggestion is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Notations that are an unnecessary sinfest of indices and make the eyes glaze over should be avoided. You want to use notations that clean and easy to read. A simple substitution here of $x = n_A, y = n_b$ would make this much easier for others to follow, and easier on yourself as well. If you like, when you get done with the calculation, you can put your indices back in.

Answer (score 0):

As you've already noticed, the minimum occurs when $n_A = n_B$, so try setting them both to $x$. Then
$$E = (1+V)x^2 - (1+2\mu)x$$
This is a parabola whose midpoint is $x = {-b\over 2a} = {1 + 2\mu\over 1 + V}$.

Because it is symmetric about this value of $x$, the closest integer to $x$ will have the lowest energy (if the graph was not symmetric, it is possible that a farther integer has lower energy - you can't just assume that the closest integer is the one you want in general). Letting $n$ be the common integer value,

$$ {1 + 2\mu\over 1 + V} - {1\over 2} \le n \le {1 + 2\mu\over 1 + V} + {1\over 2}$$

where if equality occurs on one side, then it also occurs on the other (there are 2 values of $n$ with the same minimum energy).